# Counterexample for Converse of Surjective Homomorphisms

Tags: group-homomorphism, universal-algebra

In universal algebra, I am trying to find a counterexample using groups for the converse of the following:

> If $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are algebras, and $\phi:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ is a surjective homomorphism and the identity $\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{t}$ holds in $\mathcal{A}$, then it also holds in $\mathcal{B}$.

I was thinking the trivial homomorphism could possibly be a counterexample: $G$ any non-abelian group, $H$ any abelian group, $\phi: G \to H$ defined by $\phi(g)=1$ and the identity can be commutativity. If $H$ is not trivial, then $\phi$ is not surjective.

Is my counterexample too complicated or wrong? Any advice on how to find a simple one?

Comment: But the statement is correct; it's very easy to see that it is

Comment: Your counterexample is right. The identity $xy=yx$ holds trivially in the trivial group, but not in any non-abelian group. The comment that follows (if $H$ is not trivial...) seems redundant, since, by hypothesis, $\phi$ is surjective; it just tells us that with that trivial homomorphism you only have a counterexample to the converse of the result if the group it maps to is also trivial.

Comment: @Max I think you misread the question. The goal is to find a counterexample to the **converse** of the statement. Thus, an identity that holds in $\mathcal B$ but not in $\mathcal A$, while $\phi:\mathcal A \to\mathcal B$ is surjective.

Comment: It should also be pointed that you don't need the specific case of groups, since a counterexample can be found for any non-trivial $\mathcal A$: just consider the natural homomorphism $\nu_{\theta}:\mathcal A\to\mathcal A/\theta$, where $\theta = A^2$ and the identity is $x=y$.

Comment: @amrsa : my bad, I indeed misread; sorry about that !

Comment: @amrsa Thank you for your input! Must I have a counterexample that causes $\phi$ to be non-surjective or is this is an hypothesis, and so $\phi$ must be defined as surjective?

Comment: Well the converse of the statement would be, if $\phi:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is surjective and $s=t$ holds in $\mathcal B$ then it holds in $\mathcal A$, so it is still for a surjective homomorphism, in my interpretation. As I wrote in my comment, it is false in any kind of algebra, provided $\mathcal A$ is non-trivial.

Comment: @amrsa you could make [that comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077816/counterexample-for-converse-of-surjective-homomorphisms#comment6345996_3077816) an answer.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks for the encouragement :) The comment wasn't a straight answer to the question. I made it into an answer and noted how it can be changed to make the OP solution a particular case (of the changed version).

Answer (score 2):

For any kind of algebra (regardless of the operations it has) the converse of that result is indeed false.
Just consider that if $\mathbf A$ is an algebra, then $\theta = A^2$ is a congruence on $\mathbf A$, and the quotient $\mathbf A/\theta$ is a one-element algebra.
Now, one-element algebras satisfy the equation $x=y$, and they're the only ones that do.
So if $\mathbf A$ is a non-trivial algebra (if it has more than one element), you can consider $\mathbf B = \mathbf A/\theta$, and the only possible map $\phi:\mathbf A \to \mathbf B$ is a surjective homomorphism, showing that the converse of the result is false.

Notice that it is necessary that $\mathbf A$ is non-trivial, since trivial algebras (trivially) satisfy any equation whatever.
Now you can just as well replace $x=y$ by any equation that you know that the non-trivial algebra $\mathbf A$ doesn't satisfy (because $\mathbf A/\theta$ always does).
In particular, if $\mathbf A$ is a non-commutative group, you can consider the identity $xy=yx$, as you did.